# can we use tornado asynchronous library in django to achieve asynchronous web request inside django views?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

I am having the Django project, have to request external api to get data and that should be asynchronous. but in Django, there is no asynchronous library. so that could I use tornado asynchronous library inside the Django app? is that works? please elaborate on your answer. thank you in advance.